# Apply Based on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement and I am trying to have line 5 to only start doing its process if the ORDER and ITM are the same from the previous row.

P.S I was having issues with creating a table here to show my output, so I just pasted in image for reference.

**Initial Code:**

```
SELECT TOP (50)
CAST(A.DATE as date)
     ,A.ORDER
     ,A.ITM
     ,ISNULL(A.DATE - LAG(A.DATE) OVER (ORDER BY A.DATE),Null) as 'Test' 
 
 FROM Table1 as A
 LEFT JOIN Table2 as B on A.ORDER = B.ORDER
 
 GROUP BY
 A.DATE
     ,A.ORDER
     ,A.ITM
     ,B.DATE
 
 Order By A.DATE ASC
```

**What I received**

[Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bOii.png)

**What I need help with**

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulT2N.png)

Still working on it, I did order it by Order, Item, and Date.

Comment: `CASE [Order] WHEN Lines THEN...`?

Comment: Why are you using a `GROUP BY` here? You have no aggregation. Also, your code is in a quoteblock, implying you've copied that code from someone else; if so you ***must*** follow the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Who and what are you quoting?

Comment: Thank you for the info about the quoteblock, I hope I was able to answer your question regarding the GROUP BY. The group is in here because there could be multiple orders from the same day. If I don't GROUP IT, it will give false info.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is still there, so not really; it's not needed so should be removed. If you're getting "duplicates" then likely your `JOIN` isn't correct or you should should be using `DISTINCT`; `GROUP BY` implies aggregation and you have no aggregation. I assume the `CASE` expression worked?

Comment: I will definitely let you know on the 'CASE' clause. Trying to add it now, trying to figure on how to imply in the case statement that if the current ORDER and ITM is the same from above, THEN subtract current DATE with the DATE above, ELSE Null.

Also looking into the GROUP BY too. Thx!

Comment: HI! Thank you so much I was able to do it! Everything is working perfectly.

Regarding the group by, I removed it and got an error that the Date needs to be in a group by clause. 

That doesn't matter, as you helped me with my main issue. Thank you!

Comment: @kidNamedJP post your solution as an answer and self-accept as it may help someone else (which is the intention of this site). (And check out some other questions for how to format data so you can do it correctly for your next question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

may help:

,ISNULL(A.DATE - LAG(A.DATE) OVER (Partition by A.ORDER ORDER BY A.DATE),Null) as 'Test'